# Aren't questions about possible vulnerabilities (or undesireable features) of Android on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the [android](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) tag I'm seeing a wide variety of topics:

- [How effective is a feature protecting data](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/are-there-actually-any-advantages-to-android-full-disk-encryption)
- [Why apps ask for more privileges they need](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36316/why-do-a-lot-of-android-apps-like-linkedin-require-many-unrelated-privileges)
- [What dangers represent a certain feature](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9416/what-risk-does-carrier-iq-pose-exactly)
- [What dangers represent not updating](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8548/android-security-without-updates)
- [Apps doing whatever they want without permission](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67329/skype-called-someone-and-connected-to-them-with-no-action-on-my-part-what-do-i)
- Couple of "list of X" questions
- etc.

Now, [my question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/85268/27973) in couple of words is "how my phone was wiped out without my permission" which seems to fall in the scope considering the above questions, in the way of "X did Y without permission, why?" or "what feature/vulnerability allowed third party do Y?", yet was closed and deleted. Everything else was explained in the question:

- what assets you are trying to protect (Android phone)
- who uses the asset you're trying to protect, and who you think might want to abuse it (and why) (considering the kind of undesirable behavior, everyone using an Android phone)
- what steps you've already taken to protect that asset (I didn't mention this, ok, but nobody asked)
- what risks you think you still need to mitigate (the ability to wipe a phone without the owner being aware that it can be done)

Exactly, what part of the help center says (or doesn't) a question about finding out a possible vulnerability on a Android (or any mobile) is out of scope?

Comment: I think all those who voted to close agreed it was off topic, and so did I. The question you wrote was not a security question. You asked how it appeared to be factory reset. Nothing to do with security. Just normal phone functionality.

Comment: @RoryAlsop a phone functionality that makes impossible recovery of the aparatus and any kind of protection and tracking mechanism worthless. Aren't those kind of (default) configurations the ones IT sec rant so much about?

Comment: No. Because it doesn't do that. Factory reset is a very useful and normal function.

Comment: @RoryAlsop again, not if I'm not the one that triggers it.

Comment: Braiam, the problem is that you are not asking about a vulnerability - you are asking about an existing feature/design. And just because you personally are not thrilled at the result of this feature in this specific situation, doesn't mean that the feature itself is problematic. (E.g. if you never got the phone back, wouldn't you prefer a reset over data leakage?).  Now, as asked, your question is focusing on relationship between OS-provided factory reset, as opposed to the possibility of wiping the OS and reinstalling. That is not security related, and btw these are functionally equivalent.

Comment: On the other hand, an interesting consequence of your situation, that I think may have also been bothering you in your comment to @RoryAlsop: If you have set up some form of tracking mechanism, to enable you to find your lost/stolen phone, then you wouldn't want the thief to disable that mechanism, via factory reset? Now, that IS a security question (or rather the basis for one), but that's not what you'd asked...

Comment: @AviD of course that was asked. Security design or not, shouldn't invalidate recovery mechanisms which is why I focused on factory reset and not on data wiping.

Comment: Braiam, if you could edit your question to make it clearer that that is the focus of your question, I'm sure @RoryAlsop would agree it should be opened (note though that just "I don't like this!" is not a question, nor even "they shouldn't do that because of this". It needs to be an actual, answerable question...)